# A better way of create a file if it doesn't exist using Ansible?

Tags: ansible, task, file-exists

I'd like to create an ansible task. The playbook itself should install and configure some settings in my new linux environment, so, one of the thinks I need to do is to install zsh, and after that, write one line to /etc/zsh/zshenv this way:

```
- name: Check if /etc/zsh/zshenv exists
  ansible.builtin.stat:
    path: "/etc/zsh/zshenv"
  register: file_status


- name: Creates /etc/zsh/zshenv if it doesn't exists
  ansible.builtin.file:
    path: /etc/zsh/zshenv
    state: touch
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
  when: not file_status.stat.exists


- name: configure ZDOTDIR en /etc/zsh/zshenv
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/zsh/zshenv
    line: 'ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh/'
    state: present
```

I'd like to know if ther's any way to use just one or two tasks instead of three. Even better, as I have no experience running ansible, I'd like to know if there's a better way of doing this.

Thanks a lot in advance!!

Comment: Please edit your question title so that it's more specific.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Ansible modules are idempotent by default - you don't need to check if the file exists.
2. `lineinfile` module has the `create` parameter to create a file if it doesn't exist yet
3. it also allows to set the `mode`, `group`, and `owner` just like `file` module does.

To sum up, you only need one task to achieve your goal:

```yaml
- name: Configure ZDOTDIR en /etc/zsh/zshenv
  ansible.builtin.lineinfile:
    path: /etc/zsh/zshenv
    line: 'ZDOTDIR=$HOME/.config/zsh/'
    create: true
    state: present
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: '0644'
```

Comment: This solution is perfect for my purposes. Thank you very much for your help!!